# How to integrate Sengrid API with CI as a library

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

My application is running with CI and for e-mail delivery I'm using Sendgrid API.

My intetion is to use the SendGrid API as a library, so I can load it like:
`$this->load->library('my_ci_lib');`

Searching for some examples, the only result I found was setting Sendgrid SMTP configs in Native CI Email library and extending it.

How can I use the Sendgrid API in CI?

This is I used to use Sendgrid API in raw PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../../class/SendGrid/sendgrid-php.php');

function welcomeEmail($email, $firstName, $password){
    require_once('_key.php');
    $chaves = array('{name}', '{key}');
    $template = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('../../templates/welcomePass.html'));
    $template = str_replace($chaves, array(utf8_decode($firstName), $password), $template);

    // $mail->SetFrom('no-reply'.rand(1, 100).'@domain.com.br', 'Domain');
    // $mail->Subject = utf8_decode('Seja bem-vindo(a)!');
    // $mail->Body = $template;
    // $mail->isHTML(true);
    // $mail->addTo($email);
    // //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

    $mail = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
    $mail->setFrom("connectz.no-reply".rand(1, 100)."@domain.com.br", "CONNECTZ");
    $mail->setSubject("Seja bem-vindo(a)!");
    $mail->addTo($email);
    $mail->addBcc("joao.souza@domain.com.br");
    $mail->addContent("text/html", utf8_encode($template));
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($key);

    $response = $sendgrid->send($mail);
    // print $response->statusCode() . "<br>";
    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($response->headers()).'</pre><br>';
    // print $response->body() . "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably not the best way to do this but I had to do the following to integrate Cloudinary and MongoDB into my CodeIgniter based site.

In the folder `application/library` I created a file `Cloudinarylib.php` with a folder called `cloudinary` that had all of the necessary files.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * This is a "dummy" library that just loads the actual library in the construct.
 * This technique prevents issues from CodeIgniter 3 when loading libraries that use PHP namespaces.
 * This file can be used with any PHP library that uses namespaces.  Just copy it, change the name of the class to match your library
 * and configs and go to town.
 */

class Cloudinarylib
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        // include the cloudinary library within the dummy class
        require('cloudinary/src/Cloudinary.php');
        require('cloudinary/src/Uploader.php');
        require('cloudinary/src/Api.php');

        // configure Cloudinary API connection
        \Cloudinary::config($this->CI->config->item('cloudinary'));
    }
}
```

I was then able to load the library using `$this->load->library('cloudinarylib');` and run scripts like `\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("https://www.example.com/uploads/".$file);`

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could also add functions to the new library class to perform certain tasks. Without making calls like `\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("https://www.example.com/uploads/".$file);`